# I want display avatar from API data Android Java

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a data list [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AhWH.png)

and I want show detail information whenever user clicked the list, but I just can show Name and Email only, not the avatar. [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV1g6.png)

Im using putExtra and getExtra for the data migration

here is my RecycleAdapter.java

```
package com.vyzyz.modul1_kel03;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.vyzyz.modul1_kel03.DetailActivity;
import com.vyzyz.modul1_kel03.R;

import java.util.List;

public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<DataItem> dataUser;
    private Context mContext;


    public RecycleAdapter(List<DataItem> dataUser, Context mContext) {
        this.dataUser = dataUser;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_list_user, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.tvFirstName.setText(dataUser.get(i).getFirstName());
        viewHolder.tvLastName.setText(dataUser.get(i).getLastName());
        viewHolder.tvEmail.setText(String.format("Email : %s", dataUser.get(i).getEmail()));
        Glide.with(mContext).load(dataUser.get(i).getAvatar()).into(viewHolder.imgPhotoUser);

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nameF", dataUser.get(i).getFirstName());
                intent.putExtra("nameL", dataUser.get(i).getLastName());
                intent.putExtra( "email", dataUser.get(i).getEmail());
                intent.putExtra("ava", dataUser.get(i).getAvatar());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataUser.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imgPhotoUser;
        private TextView tvFirstName, tvLastName, tvEmail;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgPhotoUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo_user);
            tvFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_first_name);
            tvLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_last_name);
            tvEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_email);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my DetailActivity.java

```
package com.vyzyz.modul1_kel03;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvNama, tvEmail;
    private ImageView tvPhoto;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        tvNama = findViewById(R.id.tv_first_name);
        tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        tvPhoto = findViewById(R.id.detail_photo);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
            String nama = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameF");
            tvNama.setText(nama);
            String mail = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
            tvEmail.setText(mail);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(dataUser.get(i).getAvatar()).into(viewHolder.imgPhotoUser);
//            String poto = getIntent().getStringExtra("ava");
//            tvPhoto.setImageResource(poto);

        }

    }
}
```

any solution?

I want show detail information whenever user clicked the list, but I just can show Name and Email only, not the avatar. [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV1g6.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question dataUser.get(i).getAvatar() returns the string. So rather than using that in DetailActivity, putExtra that string and fetch it in DetailActivity then use it in glide.

The cause of the problem might be not getting the url of image.

Also, please provide some more information. These info. is not sufficient to solve the issue. For ex. How can you use dataUser in DetailActivity as it's not even declared in the class(it will throw compile time error)!!